# Accessing a non-existent attribute on a Vue instance silently fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue and have two instances, `vm1` and `vm2` on the same page.

First of all, the scoping is bizarre. Instance attributes are scoped by the DOM element rather than dot operator in curly braces:

`{{ attr1 }}` rather than `{{ vm.attr1 }}`

Not only this, but the magical scoping silently fails when the attribute doesn't exist!

The code below executes without error. Notice `toggle` references non-existent `is_visible` on `vm`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"</script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var vm1 = new Vue({
          el: '#vm1',
          data: {
            message: 'vm1',
          },
          methods:{
            toggle: function(){
              this.is_visible = !this.is_visible;
            }
          }
        });
        var vm2 = new Vue({
            el: '#vm2',
            data: {
              message: 'vm2',
            },
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vm1">
      <h1 v-on:click="toggle()">{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="vm2">
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the exact problem?

Comment: Difficulty debugging.

Comment: could you clarify more?

Comment: How am I supposed to debug code that silently fails when referenced attributes don't exist?

Comment: i understood that you supposed that when you have no referenced attributes, the code will fail ?

Comment: Well, I would expect a warning or something in the browser console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179776/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-tom-russell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instance attributes are scoped by the DOM element rather than dot operator in curly braces
>
> ```
> {{ attr1 }} rather than {{ vm.attr1 }}
> ```

Yes, that's how Vue properties are accessed in the template (without referencing `vm` or `this`).

> the magical scoping silently fails when the attribute doesn't exist!

That's not a silent failure. That just happens to be valid JavaScript. In `toggle()`, the code is attaching a new property named `is_visible` and setting its value to the negation of itself. Initially, it's undefined, so the negation result is `true`.

```js
function Foo() {
  console.log({foo1: this.foo});
  this.foo = !this.foo;
  console.log({foo2: this.foo});
}

new Foo();
```

Vue does not require all properties to be declared in `data()`. You can attach a new property to the component instance at any time. However, properties not declared in `data()` are non-reactive. This can be useful for local variables that don't need to be in the template (e.g., timer IDs).

Comment: That helps. I had forgotten about that little quirk of Javascript.